# API Gateway Custom Authorizer never calling Target lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have setup a custom authorizer per the spec: [AWS Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-use-lambda-authorizer.html), I have enabled the API gateway, setup the authorizer, and can get the cloudwatch logs to show authorized.

Every call is redirected to what looks like a url to my function, but only ever fails with a "400 bad request":

```
Sending request to https://lambda.$REGION.amazonaws.com/2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda:$REGION:$AID:function:$LAMBDA/invocations
Received response. Integration latency: 1 ms
Endpoint response body before transformations: <html> <head><title>400 Bad Request</title></head> <body bgcolor="white"> <center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center> </body> </html>
Endpoint response headers: {Server=awselb/2.0, Date=Sun, 30 Sep 2018 04:32:01 GMT, Content-Type=text/html, Content-Length=138, Connection=close}
Lambda invocation failed with status: 400. Lambda request id: N/A
```

Is this permissions somewhere? The Api Gateway can call my "login" api just fine.

If i call the target lambda through the console with the "TEST" button it works fine.

any thoughts?

Comment: Did you ever get to the bottom of this?

Comment: @Mat yes, let me follow up tonight on this, i got it working in my personal AWS account...